# Office js getFileAsync not working in office for mac

Tags: macos, office-js, office-addins, office365api

I want to open a document as pdf with this function:

Office.context.document.getFileAsync(Office.FileType.Pdf, { sliceSize: 65536 }, function (result) { });

In Windows (Word 2016 & office 365) this works correctly, but on Mac (Word for Mac) it shows this error message: **A footer of section 1 is set outside the printable area of the page. Do you want to continue?**

How can this error message be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting this. This is effectively a bug, we fixed it and the fix is included in the update coming in June.